# SignalR only client calling is getting the update from server. MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, signalr

I have a situation where I retrieve what I need from hub response but then it does not broadcast it to all users and only the user that makes the call receives the update on browser.

My model originally comes as

```
<button>
    <span id="MySpan">@Html.ValueFor(m => m.MyCount)</span>
</button>
```

Here is my function:

```
myHubProxy.client.handleMyJob = function () 
{
    myHubProxy.server.getTheCounts().done(function (model) {
        var modelJson = JSON.parse(model);
        updateTheCounts(modelJson);
    });
};

$.connection.hub.start();
```

At this point I have what I need in modelJson a count of updated #s.

and then I have my updateTheCounts as so:

```
 function updateTheCounts(model) {
    $('#MySpan").text(model.FirstCount);
 }
```

Now I get the update for the client that triggered this request but not any other clients.

On my signalR I specified that all should receive..

Update: My hub class

```
 context.Clients.All.handleMyJob();

 public string GetPrintJobsCounts()
 {
     var model = new SomeModel();        
     model.FirstCount = counts.MyCount ?? 0;
     return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model).ToString();
 }
```

Comment: which signalr is this? the one for .net core or framework? and can you update your hub class as well?

Comment: @Neville Nazerane It is .NET framework.

Comment: ok post the hub class. because you need to send to all clients from that class

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Just so you know, I have other bits and pieces that work except this one.

Comment: I usually send to all clients by running `Clients.All` inside the hub class

Comment: @NevilleNazerane ... context.Clients.All check first line of my hub class.

Comment: ok i see that. but it is shown outside any function. i also don't see what is `context`. is this a class extending `Hub`?

Comment: basically when anyone connects to the socket the count gets incremented right?

Comment: Yup, that is basically what happens.

Comment: in my answer, i have shown how data can be passed from the server. for security reasons `myHubProxy.server` should not fetch anything from the server that is linked to any other client. the server needs to push the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling `All.handleMyJob`, you can use the `On` function in your hub proxy in js.

```
myHubProxy.on("handleMyJob", function(){

});
```

However if you would like to pass any data on the server side, you can use `Clients.All.handleMyJob(someData)` and in js you can use:

```
myHubProxy.on("handleMyJob", function(someData){

});
```